# Need help for assigning a variable with discord bot command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so I am trying to build my own discord bot with discord.js. There is one really important thing that I want to achieve.
I want to reassign a variable through a bot command. My current code looks like this:

```
client.on("message", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "boosting")) {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("0xd08d11")
      .setTitle("**Random Title**")
      .setDescription(Some description)
      .addFields(
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' }, //spacer
        { name: "Person 0", value: 'Personvalue', inline: true },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' }, //spacer
        { name: 'Price', value: 'Pricevalue', inline: true },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' }, //spacer
        { name: 'Person 1', value: '40k', inline: true },
        { name: 'Person 2', value: '40k', inline: true },
        { name: 'Person 3', value: '40k', inline: true },
        { name: 'Person 4', value: '40k', inline: true },
      )
      .setThumbnail(logo)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter('created by me or something like that');
    client.channels.cache.get(`here_is_my_channel_id`).send(embed); 
  }
});

client.login(config.token)
```

Okay, so right now I can type .boosting to get an embed message from my bot, but the thing is, that i want to type .boosting Variable1 Variable2 and so on to give new values to the attributes of the embed message. And with attributes I mean something like the description or the fields name or values. I tried something like this:

```
let Variable = "Test";

client.on("message", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "boosting" + " " + Variable)) {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("0xd08d11")
      .setTitle("**Random Title**")
      .setDescription(Variable)
      .addFields(
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' }, //spacer
        { name: "Person 0", value: 'Personvalue', inline: true },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' }, //spacer
        { name: 'Price', value: 'Pricevalue', inline: true },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' }, //spacer
        { name: 'Person 1', value: '40k', inline: true },
        { name: 'Person 2', value: '40k', inline: true },
        { name: 'Person 3', value: '40k', inline: true },
        { name: 'Person 4', value: '40k', inline: true },
      )
      .setThumbnail(logo)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter('created by me or something like that');
    client.channels.cache.get(`here_is_my_channel_id`).send(embed); 
  }
});

client.login(config.token)
```

Now I can write .boosting Test and the description of this embed message will have this as it's value.
I know that I need to define the variable, but is there any possibility to reassign it with a bot command? So it can change from the value "Test" to "something" for example. Appreciate every help!

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can split your the message into an array of words:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(/ +/).slice(1)

// example: `.boosting hello people of the world`
// returns: ['hello', 'people', 'of', 'the', 'world']
```

So, if you'd like to get the first argument (word), you can use `args[0]`. For the second, `args[1]`, and so on.

You updated code:

```js
client.on("message", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "boosting" + " " + Variable)) {
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(/ +/).slice(1)
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("0xd08d11")
      .setTitle("**Random Title**")
      .setDescription(args[0])
      .addFields(
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' }, //spacer
        { name: "Person 0", value: 'Personvalue', inline: true },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' }, //spacer
        { name: 'Price', value: 'Pricevalue', inline: true },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' }, //spacer
        { name: 'Person 1', value: '40k', inline: true },
        { name: 'Person 2', value: '40k', inline: true },
        { name: 'Person 3', value: '40k', inline: true },
        { name: 'Person 4', value: '40k', inline: true },
      )
      .setThumbnail(logo)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter('created by me or something like that');
    client.channels.cache.get(`here_is_my_channel_id`).send(embed); 
  }
});

client.login(config.token)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help :)